# I want to extract only the 4 consecutive numbers in the string of this column

Tags: powerquery

I am a beginner on power query Any idea to extract only the 4 consecutive numbers in the string of this column (the column has 400 rows)?

[image]

I only know Text.Select([String], {'0"…"9"}) but it will extract all the numbers, which I don't want.

Comment: did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom column that returns any four digit substring.

Please read the code comments to understand the algorithm.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "4 Digit Nums", 
    
    //for each row
    each 
        let
    
  //split by punctuation and LF 
          split = Text.SplitAny([Column1],"-.#(lf)"),
  
  //select only those segments which consist of four digits
           #"4 Digits" = List.Select(split, each Text.Length(_)=4 and List.ContainsAll({"0".."9"},Text.ToList(_)))
        in 

      //Combine the four digit strings with LF
            Text.Combine(#"4 Digits","#(lf)"))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: `ContainsAll`! Awesome! I wish had thought of that to begin with!

Answer (score 0):

If its always the first four characters after the 2nd dash, you could use

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Output", each Text.Start(Text.Split([Column1],"-"){2},4))
in #"Added Custom"
```

OR if it moves, you could try using regex in powerquery

```
//see http://www.thebiccountant.com/2018/04/25/regex-in-power-bi-and-power-query-in-excel-with-java-script/
// and https://gist.github.com/Hugoberry/4948d96b45d6799c47b4b9fa1b08eadf
//code below calls this function to look for 4 consecutive numbers
let   fx=(text,regex)=>
Web.Page(
    "<script>
        var x='"&text&"';
        var y=new RegExp('"&regex&"','g');
        var b=x.match(y);
        document.write(b);
    </script>")[Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0}

in
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Output", each fx([Column1], "[0-9]{4,}"))
in #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

**NOTE** if you have multiple items on the same row, as image may indicate, you need to do this as the first steps before the above

```
 #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let
  digits = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"},
  fIsDigit = each List.Contains(digits, _),
  fIs4Digit = each Text.Length(_) = 4 and List.AllTrue(
    Text.ToList(_),
    fIsDigit
  ),
  fFirst4DigitPart = (Source as text) => Int64.From(
    List.First(
      List.Select(
        List.Skip( // assuming it's never the first, otherwise remove List.Skip
          Text.Split(Source, ”-”),
          1
        ),
        fIs4Digit
      )
    )
  )
in
  fFirst4DigitPart
```

After debugging (caveat: not debugged), you can name this query `fFirstFourDigit` and use it like

```
  ...
  #"Add DigitPart" = Table.AddColumn(
    Source,
    "DigitPart",
    fFirstFourDigit,
    Int64.Type
  ),
  ...
```

Interestingly, Power Query is very efficiently lazy. The `List.Select` doesn't test all parts and *then* pass it to `List.First`. Instead, if `parts{2}` is a 4-digit number then the `List.First` code above takes just as long whether `parts` has 3 elements or 30 thousand!

Comment: Also, in case you didn't know about `each` vs fat arrows, `each` is just shorthand . `each Text.From(_) as nullable text`, `(_) as nullable text => Text.From(_)`, and `Text.From` are all equivalent.

Comment: Also also, Ron's answer is better than mine. 